# Using two different network adapter simultaniously

Tags: c#, network-programming

There are wireless adapter and dial-up modem connected to network.
And there are two files, which we need to download. (file1 & file2)

Can I download two different files via different network adapters simultaneously using C#?
For example: file1 should be downloaded through wireless adapter, and file2 via dial-up.

OS Win7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can choose your outgoing IP address in a WebRequest as follows:

```
string sendingIp = "192.168.0.1";
int sendingPort = 5000;
Uri uri = new Uri("http://google.com");
HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
ServicePoint sp = ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(uri);
sp.BindIPEndPointDelegate =
    (servicePoint,remoteEp,retryCount) =>
         {
             return new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(sendingIp),sendingPort);
         };
var data = new StreamReader(wr.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

This code does not deal with disposal correctly.

Comment: +1 In a more general way, you just have to bind to the desired interface.

Comment: I haven't go a clue how you'd go about managing which outgoing port to choose, but I suppose you could use the retryCount to step up to the next consecutive port should the bind fail and retryCount increase.